# What if a variable is declared more than one time in JAVA_OPTS in jboss 4 on linux

Tags: java, linux, jboss-4.2.x

I have declared variable `-Xmx` 2 times in JAVA_OPTS in run.sh of JBoss server.
e.g. `-Xmx512m` at say line no 15
and `-Xmx1024` at say line no 50

So which -Xmx will be actually used by server? And how to check it?

Environment :
Application Server : JBoss 4.2
OS : Linux

Answer (score 1):

It's shell script after all (`run.sh`). Most recent value is picked up. You can try it for yourself.

Create a file `run.sh` with following content

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_OPTS="Before"
JAVA_OPTS="After"
echo $JAVA_OPTS
```

and run it `./run.sh` and you should get "After" in the console. Nothing JBoss specific.

So to answer your question `-Xmx1024` will be picked up. And to answer your question so as to how to check you can use programs like `jconsole` to view your java process and check your maximum memory allocated (as you have provided in -Xmx option). You can also do something like `ps -ax | grep java` to see the Java process and the JAVA_OPTS it used.